# (MS Exchange) Mailbox database is temporary unavailable

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2007

I am trying to send mail using Exchange web service api.I am using autodiscover in order to retrieve the client profile.When I am trying send mail I am getting this error:

```
  Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponseException: 
  The mailbox database is temporarily unavailable.
```

Any tips on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you access your mail via OWA or Outlook? I'd check that first. Sounds like some issue on the backend.

Comment: You are right I'm not able to access mails from owa or outlook as well.

Comment: @MichaelMainer-Microsoft Thanks for the response. Can you please elaborate why this happened.

Comment: Sorry for getting back to you so late. There are many reasons why this could happen. I can't tell you where to start with investigating this. You will need to be an Exchange administrator to determine if your account is disabled, if the database is mounted, etc. Which version(s) of Exchange are you targeting?

Comment: Thanks for the response @MichaelMainer-Microsoft. I am using exchange server 2007 SP1. Please share some link so that i can fix it..

Comment: @nitesh-kodel123, I'm not sure how to solve this. Here is one of the many places I'd start. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb217846(v=EXCHG.80).aspx

Comment: I know your specific problem was resolved, but for others looking for more information about this very generic error I suggest checking disk space on drive where Exchange Database is stored. This error usually comes out when you run out of disk space.